# Matplotlib Hexbin log scale

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am having difficulty getting matplotlib hexbin to work with a log scale.

Here is a subset of my data and some accompanying images. The total arrays contain 6,521 values.

```
x_data = [1.81, 1.516, 6.985, 5.442, 9.419, 1.014, 0.751, 3.77, 1.337, 7.696, 0.491, 0.63, 0.484, 7.165, 0.343, 2.057, 0.218, 0.485, 3.311, 5.976, 3.904, 0.805, 3.94, 0.579, 2.325, 1.57, 0.759, 1.261, 3.975, 0.944]

y_data = [2.069, 0.076, 2.272, 0.501, 0.536, 4.144, 1.452, 7.798, 1.176, 0.832, 0.133, 0.674, 5.275, 1.87, 0.44, 0.229, 0.396, 1.448, 0.514, 0.646, 3.776, 2.2, 1.588, 1.193, 1.005, 1.181, 0.325, 2.47, 1.766, 0.754]
```

Here is a histogram of my x_data in bins of 250.

`plt.hist(x_data, bins=250)`
[image: Histogram]([![enter image description here])

There is no problem plotting my data to a log scale with a normal scatter plot.

```
plt.scatter(x_data, y_data, alpha=0.05)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
ax.set_ylim(0.001,100)
ax.set_xlim(0.001,100)
```

[image]
However, when I try to implement a hexbin I get something like this. I've trying playing with the gridesize=, bins=, and mincnt= and couldn't really get anywhere.

```
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
ax.set_ylim(0.001,100)
ax.set_xlim(0.001,100)
plt.hexbin(x_data, y_data, gridsize=(150,150), mincnt=2)
```

[image]

I finally tried using a symlog scale. It worked somewhat of what I expected from a log scale, but couldn't force the axes to go lower than 0.1 even if I set minimum values of the x and y lims to 0.0001

```
plt.xscale('symlog')
plt.yscale('symlog')
ax.set_ylim(0.0001,100)
ax.set_xlim(0.0001,100)
plt.hexbin(x_data, y_data, gridsize=(150,150), mincnt=2)
```

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not surprised that hexbin does not work on a log scale. The reason is the perculiar transform it uses. However, for precisely that reason hexbin has arguments `xscale` and `yscale`. Did you try to use those?

Comment: Ahhh! Thank you, I really wouldn't have thought there would be a difference from using those and the normal xscale and yscale! This solved it.

Answer (score 6):

I assume you want the histogram to be on a log scale, rather than the axes.

Matplotlib gives you 3 arguments: `bins`, `xscale`, and `yscale` that all can be set to `log`. When you want both axes to be on a log scale, setting `bins='log'` worked great for me.